# "Length" of spin vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, observables

*Quantum mechanics* ,McIntyre,pg 58

> For the case of spin $1 / 2$, note that the expectation value of the operator $S^{2}$ is
> $$
> \left\langle\mathbf{S}^{2}\right\rangle=\frac{3}{4} h^{2}
> $$
> which would imply that the "length" of the spin vector is
> $$
> |\mathbf{S}|=\sqrt{\left|{S^{2}}\right|}=\sqrt{3} \frac{\hbar}{2} .
> $$
> This is appreciably longer than the measured component of $\hbar / 2$, implying that the spin vector  can never be fully aligned along any axis.

I've two doubts regarding this.

- If I can't simultaneously measure the three components of spin and a measurement of a component disturbs the other components,. then how can we talk about the length of the spin vector?
- If "the spin vector  can never be fully aligned along any axis" then it can't exist in space, because wherever it points I can choose that direction to be my X axis.

Why does the author then talk about length of spin?

Comment: You do see that the expression for the "length" is exactly what you'd write classically for the length of the vector $\vec S$, right?

Comment: Yes the way I understood the author was that he meant the length in the classical sense.

Comment: You understand the  flakey [pictorial model geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number#As_a_component_of_angular_momentum) of such vectors, right? Many wise people prefer to ignore it for the very reasons you mention. It is only a cartoon.

Comment: @cosmas Zachos, yes that picture is also presented in the book. Isn't it better to give it up altogether?

Comment: It’s subjective. It does not help me calculate, intuit, analyze, or visualize anything better. Does it you?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, no ,I think that it's confusing. Thank you for your help. :)